# Short story about people who are unknowingly imprisoned by aliens in some sort of giant dome or underground chamber

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I'm trying to find a short story I read a while ago about people who are unknowingly imprisoned by aliens in some sort of giant dome or underground chamber. They don't realize they are imprisoned until someone finds a crack that leads to the outside world. Most of their fellows don't believe the outside world exists and won't go through the crack, so a few intrepid people exit through the crack and live their lives in the outside world, not realizing that this is just another layer of imprisonment.

If anyone knows the title or has a link, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do the aliens not know they are imprisoning some humans, or do the humans not know they are imprisoned?

Comment: This is a fairly common setup for a sci fi story. Jimmy, can you give us more information about when and where you read it? Was this in a 70s anthology? Earlier? Later? Was it American, UK, or from Australia/NZ? I do have one idea but it's a story from the 1960s and the people who exit the "dome" are hunters.

Answer (score 0):

Plot, if not all details (no aliens) sounds vaguely like The Starlost--a screenplay and TV series by Harlan Ellison that was novelized as Phoenix Without Ashes by Edward Bryant.

Comment: Appreciate the reply but that's not it. This is a short story I read some time ago.